# Centering and scrolling UIScrollView content with dimensions both larger and smaller

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

How do you handle centering and scrolling content in a **UIScrollView** when the dimensions are both larger and smaller than the containing scroll view?

I have been trying to set values in **layoutSubviews** to handle the initial centering of the content, while still allowing for scrolling.

If the content is smaller in both dimensions, I can just set the **frame** and the image is properly centered for all rotations and orientations. Setting the **contentInset** will also work. **contentOffset** does not seem to work.

If the content is larger in both dimensions, I can set **contentOffset** for the initial display, and not modify it again to support scrolling.

What do I do if I have an image with one dimension larger, and the other smaller, than the scroll view?

**contentOffset** uses a **CGPoint**, and **contentInset** uses **UIEdgeInsets** (top, left, bottom, right). I have tried mixing positive and negative, since one dimension needs to be moved in and the other out, but haven't gotten anything to work.

My next thought is to resize the scroll view (and modify constraints I suppose) so that the content is never smaller than the container and use **contentOffset**.

I would really like to have a single approach that will work regardless of larger or smaller dimensions.

What is the best solution (a solution) to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping back from this, getting a better understanding of **UIScrollView**, and rethinking, I have solved my problem.

For starters, **layoutSubviews** is the wrong way to go, at least for what I need.

Trying to resize the **UIScrollView** and update constraints seemed more trouble than it was worth.

For whatever reason, it didn't initially occur to me than I could use both **contentOffset** and **contentInset** at the same time (thought it was either/or for some reason), but that was my exact solution.

```
CGRect rectContent = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectContent];
self.scrollView.contentSize = rectContent.size;

CGFloat fOffsetWidth = (rectContent.size.width < self.scrollView.bounds.size.width) ? (self.scrollView.bounds.size.width - rectContent.size.width)/2 : 0;
CGFloat fOffsetHeight = (rectContent.size.height < self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) ? (self.scrollView.bounds.size.height - rectContent.size.height)/2 : 0;

self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(fOffsetHeight, fOffsetWidth, fOffsetHeight, fOffsetWidth);
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((rectContent.size.width - self.scrollView.bounds.size.width)/2, (rectContent.size.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)/2);

imageView.image = image;

[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

All image dimension possibilities (larger/smaller, one/both) are centered in the scroll view, and a larger image dimension is scrollable while a smaller dimension remains centered.

Perfect!